# Orthonormal Sets and the Gram-Schmidt Procedure

Tags: vector-spaces

[image]

> What my problem in understanding in the above  procedure is , how they
>   constructed the successive vectors by substracting? Can you elaborate
>   please?

Comment: Please, clarify. Are you wish to know how they obtain $|w_2 \rangle$ having $|w_1 \rangle$ and so on?

Comment: @user35603, Yes you are right. I wanted to know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $|w_1\rangle=|u_1\rangle$. Let us find $|w_2\rangle$ as a linear combination of $|w_1\rangle$ and $|u_2\rangle$. Suppose
$$
  |w_2\rangle = \lambda |w_1\rangle + |u_2\rangle.
$$
Now we wish that $\langle w_1 | w_2\rangle =0$ (since $|w_1\rangle$ and $|w_2\rangle$ must be orthogonal). Multiply the above equality by $\langle w_1|$:
$$
  0=\langle w_1|w_2\rangle = \lambda \langle w_1|w_1\rangle + \langle w_1|u_2\rangle.
$$
Thus, $\lambda=-\frac{\langle w_1|u_2\rangle}{\langle w_1|w_1\rangle}$ ($\langle w_1|w_1\rangle \neq 0$ since $|w_1\rangle \neq 0$) and the formula follows.

Finally, suppose $|w_3\rangle=\lambda_1 |w_1\rangle + \lambda_2 |w_2\rangle + |u_3\rangle$. Multiply it by $\langle w_1|$ to find $\lambda_1$ and $\langle w_2|$ to find $\lambda_2$ (remember that we want $\langle w_1 | w_3\rangle =0$ and $\langle w_2 | w_3\rangle =0$).